# Spring boot: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm writing controller class and get this error:
`java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match, user_id_like, user_id_liked, user_liked_id) values (0, null, 'e89a0596-b1' at line 1`

Here is my code:
**UserController.java**

```
@Autowired
UserService userService;

@PostMapping("/like/{userLikedId}")
public String likeUser(@PathVariable(name = "userLikedId") String userLikedId,
                       @RequestBody UserInfo userInfo) {
    System.out.println(userInfo.getUserId());
    userService.likeUser(userInfo.getUserId(), userLikedId);
    return "Liked other user!";
}
```

**UserService.java**

```
@Autowired
UserLikedRepository userLikedRepository;
@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;
public UserLiked likeUser(String userLikeId, String userLikedId){
    UserLiked userLiked = new UserLiked();
    userLiked.setUserLikeId(userLikeId);
    userLiked.setUserLikedId(userLikedId);
    userLiked.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    System.out.println(userLiked.toString());

    userLikedRepository.save(userLiked);
    return userLiked;
}
```

**postman:**

```
http://localhost:8080/user/like/e89a0596-b121-4e40-8c64-844c868c2fae
raw: {
    "userLikeId": "user tesst"
}
```

**console:**

```
null
UserLiked(Id=57e176b9-3c5d-41b0-af0a-5f3bd14e0cac, userLikeId=null, userLikedId=e89a0596-b121-4e40-8c64-844c868c2fae, match=0)
```

Why do I get this errror and how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: "match" is a reserved keyword in MySql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html. Can you try renaming to something different?

Comment: Thank you, I can add it to mysql. But console still ```null
UserLiked(Id=35afbcb3-abe8-4238-b909-f595f470919d, userLikeId=null, userLikedId=e89a0596-b121-4e40-8c64-844c868c2fae, matched=0)```

Comment: Could you please add UserLike entity, and the repo classes?

Comment: @Kemal Kaplan 
Yes, it's already in my project.
I deleted some annotations.
**public class UserLiked **
    private String Id;
    private String userLikeId;
    private String userLikedId;
    private int matched;

 public interface UserLikedRepository extends JpaRepository<UserLiked, String> {}

But the point is controller class is not get data from postman.

Comment: Id in controller and in postman is not match, I fixed